# Is a cheese stick a kizais?

Tags: halacha

I want to know if a cheese stick is a kizais. Im trying to figure out if I can say a bracha achrona after eating a cheese stick. I assume they're all made about the same size.

Comment: What  is a cheese stick?

Comment: a polly-o string cheese is 28 grams. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Polly-O-String-Cheese-Mozzarella-Cheese-Snacks-24-ct-Sticks/10293364 a kzayis is 38 ml https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/4105/kzayis-a-guide-to-halachic-food-measurements/ one would need the proper density to know how cheese would convert from ml to gram. Water apparently is 27 grams to the kzayis https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/how-much-is-a-kezayis/#_ftn33

Comment: conversion can be done here https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/cooking/ml-grams.php -- margarine is the same as water but cheese isn't listed

Comment: @rosends I suppose it's typically a CYLOR issue to ask which kezayit measure to follow...

Comment: @Kazibácsi for me, it would also require consulting a scientist, a mathmatician and, probably, a dietician.

Comment: @rosends YLOR should cover all of that, shouldn't he? :-)